# VS 2013 debugger not working in Android emulator with a Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I've installed the latest VS Cordova tools (CTP3). I have the emulator running and the app will deploy to the device when I hit debug. The app loads and runs fine, but no debug data is displayed in the JavaScript console, the DOM inspector doesn't load and no break points are hit. There is some debug data being displayed in the "Output" tab.

Here is some output from the "Build" tab when I hit debug:

```
2>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
2>  Wrote out Android application name to "My App"
2>  This app does not have launcher icons defined
2>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.BlankCordovaAppV3"
2>  Running command: C:\web\cordova\sampleApp\bcv3\bc3\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --emulator --debug
2>  Skipping build...
2>  Built the following apk(s):
2>      C:\web\cordova\sampleApp\bcv3\bc3\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
2>  Installing app on emulator...
2>  Using apk: C:\web\cordova\sampleApp\bcv3\bc3\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
2>  Launching application...
2>  LAUNCH SUCCESS
2>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\web\cordova\sampleApp\bcv3\bc3\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild,--emulator,--debug
```

This is all that is displayed in the JavaScript console tab:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred
File: about:blank
```

I have previously been able to debug, but now it doesn't work except for a few random occurrences. I've tried to clear the Cordova cache and reinstalled all the Cordova tools. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to isolate the issue.

- Can you debug against other targets? (If you have VS2015 Preview, I would try the VS Emulator for Android, which can be a workaround) What about Windows?
- Can you debug other apps that are known to work (one of the samples)? If you can debug other apps, you may be running into an issue such as is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks.aspx
  In your case, the issue related to multi-page apps could apply (the console error looks like something I've seen with multi-page apps when using AngularJS).
- You might also check whether you need to install updates to the Android SDK (open SDK Manager).